# Figure out div that is visible out of four divs

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors

I need to figure out what div is visible out of four possible divs using jQuery.  Only one of those div's will be visible at any given time.

This is what I have that works so far:

```
$("#FeatureImage1:visible, #FeatureImage2:visible, #FeatureImage3:visible, #FeatureImage4:visible").attr("id");
```

Is there a way to refactor this?  Is there an easier way to figure this out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign the same class to each div then:

```
$("div.myClass:visible").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

When applicable, it's better to use contextual selectors rather than add spurious classes.  For instance, if the `<div>` elements are the only children of an element with `id="foo"`, then using `$("#foo > div:visible").attr("id")` would better reflect the purpose of the code.